# c# json search for string when I have unknown property

Tags: c#, json, system.text.json

I would like to search my json in c# for string, but the structure of the json is dynamic to me, and the property name is dynamic, this is the example of my json file:

```
[
{"Bluebook": {"Chapter8": {"Verse10":"This is some sentence"} }  }  , 
{"A person":   {"Skills":   { "Running":"Very fast" , "walking" : "not so fast" , "jumping": "high enough" }    }  } ,
{"Randomstuff": {"Highest Mountain":"Everest" , "Biggest Ocean":"Pacific" } }
]
```

So what I would like to do is search for a string such as example
If I search for `"Everest"`
Then I would like to get the key to it, or the object:

```
{"Randomstuff": {"Highest Mountain":"Everest" }}
```

Or if I search for `"high"` I would get:

```
{"A person":   {"Skills":   { "jumping": "high enough" }    }  } ,
    {"Randomstuff": {"Highest Mountain":"Everest"}}
```

How can this be done in Csharp,
I would prefer using System.text.json
Thank You very much

Comment: What is the context you are developing this for? Do you want to search in JSON files?

Comment: Its nice to hear, what you need, but what have you tried so far? What error did you get?

Comment: I have this json file with all kind of data such as song lyrics, random facts, books, and therefore, the property is dynamic. 
I would like to create a search engine for it,  so I could search for a string and give me the results.
I haven't write any code, I think it can be done by just looping through everything in the json file, but I want to see if anyone would know a more efficient way to do this. Thanks

Comment: This is a "Gimme the codes"-question. That's not what SO is for. Try to do something yourselves and write a specific question, when you run into problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the power of Regex

```
(?:\"key\"\s*\:\s*)((\[((?<g1>[^\[\]]+|(?1))*)\])|({((?<g2>[^{}]+|(?1))*)}))
```

In c#

**Note** : I use the following nugget package [Pcre.Net](https://github.com/ltrzesniewski/pcre-net) because .net doesn't support some features.

```cs
public static string GetValue(string key, string json)
{
    var pattern = $"(?:\"{key}\"\\s*\\:\\s*)((\\[((?<g1>[^\\[\\]]+|(?1))*)\\])|({{((?<g2>[^{{}}]+|(?1))*)}}))";
    var regex = new PCRE.PcreRegex(pattern);

    return regex.Match(json).Value;
}
```